# Escaping a single quote in Javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping, double-quotes, single-quotes

We're getting the firstName and lastName of customers which may contain a single quote in it. If one of the names contains a single quote, I get a script error 'Expected ";"'.

The snippet to greet the customer is:

```
greeting = "Guten Tag " + '<xsl:value-of select="cognetic_core_person/@person_firstName" />' + "&nbsp;" +'<xsl:value-of select="cognetic_core_person/@person_lastName" />' + "!";
```

I can't just use the double quote as there are double quotes in it. So

```
replace( /'/g , "\'")
```

or something similar is not working and the only proposals I've found so far.

Answer (score 0):

make it

```
replace( /'/g , "\\\'")
```

for example

`"as's".replace( /'/g , "\\\'")` //outputs as\'s

basically you need to use single slash 3 times, one slash is to escape slash itself and one to escape the quote.

Comment: The problem is it takes the replace as text:
 greeting = "Guten Tag " + 'Jéän-Françöisü'.replace(/'/g , "\\\'") + "&nbsp;" +'BO'LOMEYèéà'.replace(/'/g , "\\\'") + "!";

Comment: @Shade That is because you have enclose names in single quotes. Enclose them in double quotes as `"BO'LOMEYèéà".replace(/'/g , "\\\'")`

Comment: feeling stupid. Already tried this and didn't work, was probably another bug around when I first tried this. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Repace **'** with **`** (near escape key)

O'Doil will be O`Doil